# Specifying the Main.aux file in preferences

Tags: directory

I have a main.aux file in the folder `/248239j/Latex/main.aux`.

In the preferences within Configure Texmaker I have the Bib(la)tex set to: `%.aux`

I am receiving the error:
could not start the command: "main".aux

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The signature in the text question  is not needed in this site as your username is showed at the bottom.  Avoid also thanks and asking help , since this is already assumed and we try to maintain concise questions. Your thanks will we showed when you accept/upvote the questions.

Comment: I  guess that the `main.aux` file is not in the same directory that `main.tex`   and that `/248239j/Latex/` is not searchable (is not into the path)  or maybe the latex file is not  named `main.tex`, but with this information it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: "main.aux" isn't a command, it should be something like `biber %` in the configuration, if you want to use biber and `bibtex %`  if you want to use bibtex. In both cases don't add the extension, it is not needed and  for biber .aux is wrong anyway.

Comment: thanks, Yes changing the configuration file fixed this.  How do I mark this as answered.

Comment: @Ulrike Do you want to add an answer or do we have a duplicate around?

Comment: @Johannes_B: no idea if there is a duplicate (but I doubt it) so I converted my comment to an answer.

Comment: @Ulrike Thanks, +1 and another question off the  the list.

Answer (score 1):

Only using `%.aux` in the configuration is wrong, this expands only to a file name. There must be some application before. With your setting texmaker is trying to call the command `main.aux` and this naturally fails.

Correct would be in the configuration something like `biber %`, if you want to use biber and `bibtex %` if you want to use bibtex. In both cases don't add the extension, it is not needed and for biber `.aux` is wrong anyway.